# How to set same height for display flex childs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

Is there any way to say that the "TEST 1.1" row get the same height as the "TEST 1 TEST 1 TEST 1 TEST 1 TEST 1" only with CSS? Same should be if the "TEST 2" row includes more Text, the "TEST 2.1" row should be as height as "TEST 2".

The HTML Structure and Markup should stay like it is.

Edit: Or is there an easy way to do it with JS?

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
}

.inner {flex: 1 1 50%}

.inner-child {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px dotted;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="inner-child">
      TEST 1 TEST 1 TEST 1 TEST 1 TEST 1
    </div>
    <div class="inner-child">
      TEST 2
    </div>
    <div class="inner-child">
      TEST 3
    </div>
    <div class="inner-child">
      TEST 4
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="inner">
     <div class="inner-child">
       TEST 1.1
    </div>
     <div class="inner-child">
       TEST 2.1
    </div>
     <div class="inner-child">
       TEST 3.1
    </div>
     <div class="inner-child">
       TEST 4.1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not possible because they are not related, you should change the HTML structure, they need to become siblings, or do it with JS.

Comment: is it necessary for the markup to be like that? if not, i suggest you use position absolute for the children (1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1), rather than separating them in two different elements

Comment: Thats the problem, the markup and the HTML structure should stay like that ...

Comment: then you need to use javascript. i'd say it's impossible to achieve what you need by that markup structure

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [css grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/).

Flexbox was design to create a one dimensional array either horizontally or vertically.

While css grid was designed to accomodate two dimensional arrays (Both horizontal and vertical simultaneously.)

```css
.outer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 200px;
}

.inner-child {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px dotted;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner-child">
    TEST 1 TEST 1 TEST 1 TEST 1 TEST 1
  </div>
  <div class="inner-child">
    TEST 1.1
  </div>
  <div class="inner-child">
    TEST 2
  </div>
  <div class="inner-child">
    TEST 2.1
  </div>
  <div class="inner-child">
    TEST 3
  </div>
  <div class="inner-child">
    TEST 3.1
  </div>
  <div class="inner-child">
    TEST 4
  </div>
  <div class="inner-child">
    TEST 4.1
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing a little the html and adding `display: flex` in inner class you can do something similar to what you're looking for. Here is an example:

```css
.outer {
  width: 200px;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.inner-child {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px dotted;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="inner-child">TEST 1 TEST 1 TEST 1 TEST 1 TEST 1</div>
    <div class="inner-child">TEST 1.1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="inner-child">TEST 2</div>
    <div class="inner-child">TEST 2.1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, i already tried this, but its not possible for me to change the html structure, because its template

Comment: @RickH. Too bad I didn't read it before. Then there's no other way than JS/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Done by simple jQuery

```js
$(".outer .inner:first .inner-child").each(function(i,e){
    i += 1;
    if($(".outer .inner:last .inner-child:nth-child("+i+")").length)
    {
      var heightInFirst = $(this).height();
      var heightInSecond = $(".outer .inner:last .inner-child:nth-child("+i+")").height();

      $(".outer .inner .inner-child:nth-child("+i+")").css("height",Math.max(heightInFirst, heightInSecond)+"px");
    }
  });
```

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
}
.inner {flex: 1 1 50%}

.inner-child {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px dotted;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="inner-child">
      TEST 1 TEST 1 TEST 1 TEST 1 TEST 1
    </div>
    <div class="inner-child">
      TEST 2
    </div>
    <div class="inner-child">
      TEST 3
    </div>
    <div class="inner-child">
      TEST 4
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="inner">
     <div class="inner-child">
       TEST 1.1
    </div>
     <div class="inner-child">
       TEST 2.1
    </div>
     <div class="inner-child">
       TEST 3.1
    </div>
     <div class="inner-child">
       TEST 4.1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```